# Comparing user input to 2 element in a string array

Tags: java, arrays, equality

I have an array of first name, last name, id and email. My user will input a first name and a last name, and if found in the array, it should print all the information (first name, last name, id and email).

I've done my code but it never gets to print the information. Always says that information was not found. I imagine it's a `{}` problem, but I can't get to the problem.

Here is my code:

```java
static void liste1etudiant(String listetudiants0[][]) {
  Scanner sc0 = new Scanner(System.in);
  int i = 0, j = 0;
  String prenom, nom;
  boolean foundp = false, foundn = false;

  System.out.println("Entrez le prenom de l'etudiant a chercher");
  prenom = sc0.next();
  System.out.println("Entrez le nom de l'etudiant a chercher");
  nom = sc0.next();

  for (j = 0; j < listetudiants0.length; j++) {
    if (listetudiants0[j][i].equalsIgnoreCase(prenom)) {
      foundp = true;
    }

    if (foundp) {
      for (i = 0; i < listetudiants0[0].length; i++) {
        if (listetudiants0[j][i].equalsIgnoreCase(nom)) {
          foundn = true;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  if (foundn) {
    System.out.println(listetudiants0[j][i]);
  } else {
    System.out.println("The student is not in the table");
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "a `{}` problem"?

Answer (score 0):

For this problem, you should use an AND operator (`&&`).

With this, you can check for the name **and** surname at once. Thanks to that, you'll be able to get rid of `foundp` and `foundn`, have only one `found` variable and only one loop.

You can also use the `break` keyword to end a loop early, so that you stop the loop as soon as you find a person.

```java
static void liste1etudiant(String listetudiants0[][]) {
  Scanner sc0 = new Scanner(System.in);
  int i = 0;
  String prenom, nom;
  boolean found = false;

  System.out.println("Entrez le prenom de l'etudiant a chercher");
  prenom = sc0.next();
  System.out.println("Entrez le nom de l'etudiant a chercher");
  nom = sc0.next();

  for (i = 0; i < listetudiants0.length; i++) {
    if (listetudiants0[i][0].equalsIgnoreCase(prenom) && 
        listetudiants0[i][1].equalsIgnoreCase(nom)) {
      found = true;
      break;
    }
  }

  if (found) {
    System.out.println(listetudiants0[i][0]);
  } else {
    System.out.println("The student is not in the table");
  }
}
```

PS: When posting on StackOverflow, you should try to isolate the problem and translate everything in English